# FBA with different membership levels

Tags: forms-authentication

I need to have an FBA webapplication on sharepoint, however the customer needs to have that each user has a level: gold, platinum, silver for example.

Then based on that level, then we can give them acess to different lists, libraries, subsites, etc.

Anyone can guide me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one FBA role/group for each of your level, assign these roles to the proper permissions on your SHAREPOINT sites/lists,etc... and then assign your FBA users to your gold/silver/bronze FBA roles.

Does that make sense?